# Login on a site via google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make an extension for google chrome that watches for updating of information on a site. The problem is to do this I must to be logined on the site. Can I make an exsension so as it would ask a login and password from the site at start and then stores this information in the cookies? Does Chrome maintain abilities to make extension like this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it. If you send a request from chrome extension to www.example.com - for example, the chrome extension adds the cookies from this site to your request. If the user isn't connected to example site, you can redirect him to login page in example.com and then continue. (Of course, you have to type "www.example.com" permission in manifest.json). 
You can see sample from google- [google mail checker](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:mail%20checker).

(I'm sorry about my English).